# Change in vue composition api

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I try to emit value change in new **[Vue Composition Api](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/composition-api-faq.html)**, like this

```
<template>
  <select
    @change="handleChange()"
  >
    <option value="text">Text</option>
    <option value="image">Image</option>
  </select>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
  name: "Select",
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const handleChange = (event: any) => {
      emit("customChange", event.target.value);
    };
    return {
      handleChange,
    };
  },
};
<script/>
```

Return

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'target')

So i think is the are some error. Somebody see the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `handleChange` without arguments. Either do

```
@change="handleChange"
```

or

```
@change="handleChange($event)"
```

or

```
@change="e => handleChange(e)"
```

Any of them will pass the event as first parameter to your handler function.